# t-sql database restore without security

Tags: security, t-sql

Is there a way to ignore the security portion (users) of a database when doing a restore? I know there is a way to script them all out, but we are restoring production databases on multiple dev machines, each having their particular set of users that we need to keep. Currently they are overwritten by production users.

[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) Developer Edition (64-bit)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to eliminate the security portion from a backup. It is possible to do a schema comparison using Visual Studio 2010 or higher before doing the restore and generate a script from that to do the permission changes.

See [Compare and Synchronize Database Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193250.aspx).